# Cross platform Xamarin PCL project unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, nunit, xamarin.forms, xunit.net

I want to do unit testing my pcl xamarin project for ios,android and windows(not important).How can i do it with proper way.(i heard about Nunit or Xunit)

Project were created with visual studio and xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit 3 has support for testing Xamarin PCL projects. It is an involved process and StackOverflow questions should be much more targeted, not general how-to's, that is why you are getting down voted.

To get you started, read [Testing Xamarin Projects using NUnit 3](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/12/21/testing-xamarin-projects-using-nunit-3/).

Comment: Hi thanks.I had gone through your link and try to create Nunit 3 test project.but i am confused with how to link the pcl common project with test project.and how to run the test.normally in msunit test we can run test using right click and run tests.

Comment: Add your comments to the blog post and I will help you there. StackOverflow isn't the best place for that.